# Paragraph style footnotes within mdframed theorems?

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, mdframed

The `mdframed` package provides a nice functionality to insert footnotes inside a theorem. I am in search of a way to implement the paragraph style of footnote option within a theorem environment. This forces footnotes to appear within a single paragraph which is a very helpful option when one has many short footnotes which create a long, ugly column and waste space. I am trying to use, for example, the `para` option within the `footmisc` package. As you can see in the compilation of my MWE, the footnotes are still printing in their own paragraphs (a single column) for some reason.

Also, please note that a preferable solution would leave the option for both standard *and* paragraph style footnotes, as one may still want an occasional long footnote. For example, I know the `bigfoot` package offers this functionality with the distinct `\footnote{}` and `\footnote+{}` commands. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc} 

\declaretheorem[mdframed]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
     This is the first part of the theorem,\footnote{First footnote} this is the second part,\footnote{Second footnote} and this is the third part.\footnote{Third footnote}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some dirty work.

Use `\parfn` and `\normalfn` to change between different shapes of footnote.

Use `\parmpfn` and `\normalmpfn` to change between different shapes of footnote in `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\makeatletter

\newbox\my@footins%
\newtoks\my@output%

\long\def\my@footnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\my@footins\hbox{%
    \unhbox\my@footins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \my@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\rule{1em}\z@\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}

\def\my@makecol{%
  \setbox\footins\vbox{\footnoterule\box\my@footins}
  \my@latex@makecol%
}

\let\my@latex@makecol\@makecol
\let\my@latex@footnotetext\@footnotetext

\def\parfn{%
  \let\@makecol\my@makecol%
  \let\@footnotetext\my@footnotetext%
}%
\def\normalfn{%
  \let\@makecol\my@latex@makecol%
  \let\@footnotetext\my@latex@footnotetext%
}%

\long\def\my@mpfootnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\hbox{%
    \unhbox\@mpfootins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \my@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\rule{1em}\z@\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}

\newrobustcmd*\mymdf@footnoteoutput{%
     \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else%
          \nobreak%
          \vskip\mdf@footenotedistance@length%
          \normalcolor%
          \mdf@footnoterule%
          \noindent\unhbox\@mpfootins%
     \fi%
}

\newrobustcmd*\mymdf@footnoteinput{%
   \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}%
   \def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}%
   \c@mpfootnote\z@%
   \let\@footnotetext\my@mpfootnotetext%
}

\newcommand\my@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \@makefnmark#1}

\let\oldmdf@footnoteinput\mdf@footnoteinput%
\let\oldmdf@footnoteoutput\mdf@footnoteoutput%

\def\parmpfn{%
  \let\mdf@footnoteinput\mymdf@footnoteinput%
  \let\mdf@footnoteoutput\mymdf@footnoteoutput%
}

\def\normalmpfn{%
  \let\mdf@footnoteinput\oldmdf@footnoteinput%
  \let\mdf@footnoteoutput\oldmdf@footnoteoutput%
}

\makeatother

\declaretheorem[mdframed]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\parfn
Some text\footnote{test}

Some text\footnote{test}

\parmpfn
\begin{theorem}
     This is the first part of the theorem,\footnote{First footnote} this is the second part,\footnote{Second footnote} and this is the third part.\footnote{Third footnote}
\end{theorem}

\normalmpfn
\begin{theorem}
     This is the first part of the theorem,\footnote{First footnote} this is the second part,\footnote{Second footnote} and this is the third part.\footnote{Third footnote}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to switch back and forth between these two modes then? Distinct commands?

Comment: Sure, see the changed answer.

Comment: Final thought: Could the `\footnote` command itself have this distinction? This way I wouldn't have to constantly change the `\parmpfn` flag, and both a paragraph style and column style footnote could exist. Something like a combination of `\footnotepar{}` and just regular `\footnote{}`?

Comment: You can not let two footnote of different shapes show in the same page.